# Mongoose query, select 10 most recent document without changing order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to select from my `messages collection`, the 10 most recent messages, and return them as an array form the older to the most recent.

**Example** : `m1, m2, m3, ... [m19, m20, m22]` <-- Select last 10 but keep the order.

The `slice` operator is great because it can take value like `-10` and so select 10 last values from an array. The problem is that I want to sort the whole query response, and not a property within the response (`slice` operator takes 2 arguments, the first one is the `path`).

Actually what I do is :

```
.find({ conversation: conversationId })
      .sort('-updatedAt')
      .limit(10)
      .exec(function(err, messages) {

      });
```

But the array it returns contains messages from the most recent to the older.
What can I do to keep the good order, without reverting the whole array after the query execution ? ( `messages.reverse();` )

Comment: You have to reverse the list you get back.  Is that a problem?

Comment: No, it isn't... But I was wondering if any better solution would be possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the order to ascending(old-to-new) messages and get the last N elements that you need

```
.find().skip(db.collection.count() - N)
```

So you will get the most recent messages in ascending orden

Comment: I did'nt know about the `collection.count()`, thanks !
How about performances ?

Comment: It's going to be terrible.

Comment: So it would be better to use the `limit()` method, as in my post ?

Comment: I think that is better use it how do you wrote before and reverse the array because I agree with Robert, will be terrible the performance

Comment: MongoDB drivers compatible with the 4.0 features deprecate their respective cursor and collection count() APIs in favor of new APIs for countDocuments() and estimatedDocumentCount(). 
see [Mongodb documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

Answer (score 4):

**Get 10 latest documents**

```
MySchema.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(10)
```

**Get 10 oldest documents**

```
MySchema.find().sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(10)
```

Comment: is this valid if the id is not an increasing number? ex: uuid for instance?

Comment: Yes, it'll work but it's better to test and let the community know about other use cases.